# How to download and play an online clip?

Tags: java, file, url, audio

I want to play a wav sound available in my dropbox. When loading it using an URL, the sound is played for ~0.1 seconds and stops. No error is displayed.

I tried directly with a file and it worked. I switched to a URL and then it fails. I believe the file is not fully/sufficiently loaded before the clip starts playing it.

Here is my minimal code:

```
URL u = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqm81qa10825da8?dl=1");
        Clip clip = loadSound(u);

        clip.start();
```

The loadSound function is:

```
        try{
            BufferedInputStream in = null;


            if(URLManagerUtils.isLocalFile(soundFile))
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(soundFile.getFile()));
            else 
                in = new BufferedInputStream(URLManagerUtils.loadFromFile(soundFile));

            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, audioStream.getFormat());

            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {

                @Override
                public void update(LineEvent event) {
                    if(event.getType().equals(LineEvent.Type.STOP))
                    {
                    }
                }
            });
            clip.open(audioStream);
            return clip;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            throw new Error("Error trying to read sound file:"+soundFile+"\n"+sw.toString());
        }
    }
```

I want the sound to be fully played. Now it is only played for ~0.1s and then stops.
I want and have no error message.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: alerte is 0.4 sec - so I dont know what you are talking about

Comment: Hello gpasch!
I might be wrong, but over here, alerte is 4 seconds long (both using a standard player and when playing it from a local file with Java).